# Display current screen size - Responsive Design tools

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, responsive-design, browser-plugin

I'm doing a lot of responsive design development at the moment, as are all front-end devs.

One thing i would love to know is the exact current screen size.

Chrome has it:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh

How can I display the current screen size with Firefox?

Comment: Screen size or browser size?

Comment: browser size... for responsive designs and media queries

Comment: Displaying the browser's dimensions is a setting in Opera that has been around for years (almost positive it was in version 6).

Comment: they are good kids :) Frustrating that firefox does not, moreover chrome also displays which media query is active in the dev toolbar when inspecting and viewing element styles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its a very old question but worth mentioning.

Firefox now has "[Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View)" Which is the best to doing responsive testing that I've seen on any browser.

the shortcut is `Cntrl+Shift+M` and you're in a fantastic mobile view with complete control over the size of the screen whilst still being able to open the dev tools.

[image]

**Update - Chrome Tools**

Its been a while since this answer and since `Firefox`'s mobile development tools haven't changed a whole deal, `Google Chromes` have changed a whole lot and are so fantastic it would seem silly not to share for those that haven't already used it.

Hit `F12` then this will open, then hit the small mobile icon to bring up the mobile development tools:

[image: How to Enable Mobile Dev Tools on Chrome]

This will open the mobile dev tools which looks like this
[image: Such lovelyness it hurts]

From here you can change all sorts of things, but easily between devices with the pre-defined devices and user-agents automatically set for you.

More over you can change things, like touch, geo-location etc

Answer (score 6):

Like this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krWLA/3/)

```
$(window).on('resize', showSize);

showSize();

function showSize() {
    $('#size').html('HEIGHT : '+$(window).height()+'<br>WIDTH : '+$(window).width());
    $('#size2').html('HEIGHT : '+screen.height+'<br>WIDTH : '+screen.width);
}
​
```

**EDIT:** added screen size as well, use whatever you need!

Comment: Thanks, i thought about writting a plugin to do this exact thing only display it nicely and in the corner only when resizing.... Might be i have to do this... But really i'm after a nice non intrusive way of displaying it you see.

Comment: That's just a little CSS, you'll figure that part out easy, and style it however you like it? Something like this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/krWLA/4/)

Comment: ye, i wrote one a few months back, but i couldn't be bothered to keep it, as it wasn't clean or nice. I was just hoping for a firefox plugin like as i said, chrome has one. Rather than me spending a day writing this thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can put this as a bookmark. It should (hopefully) work cross-browser. Click on the display to get rid of it. http://jsfiddle.net/krWLA/8/

```
(function() {
    var v=window,d=document;
    v.onresize = function() {
        var w = v.innerWidth ? v.innerWidth :
                d.documentElement.clientWidth,
            h = v.innerHeight ? v.innerHeight : 
                d.documentElement.clientHeight,
            s = d.getElementById('WSzPlgIn'),
            ss;
        if (!s) {
            s = d.createElement('div');
            s.id = 'WSzPlgIn';
            d.body.appendChild(s);
            s.onclick = function() {
                s.parentNode.removeChild(s)
            };
            ss = s.style;
            ss.position = 'absolute';
            ss.bottom = 0;
            ss.right = 0;
            ss.backgroundColor = 'black';
            ss.opacity = '.5';
            ss.color = 'white';
            ss.fontFamily = 'monospace';
            ss.fontSize = '10pt';
            ss.padding = '5px';
            ss.textAlign = 'right';
        }
        s.innerHTML = 'w ' + w + '<br />h ' + h;
    };
})()​
```